# How to fix "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm trying to post images in the database with base_64 code. But I get "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.".
What am I doing wrong?

I already tried to delete the route "Route::get('/image', 'ImageController@create');".

I also tried to change the route "Route::post('/imagepost', 'ImageController@store');" to Route::get.
But it all seems to fail.

My routes:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/image', 'ImageController@create');
Route::post('/imagepost', 'ImageController@store');
Route::resource('/image', 'ImageController');
Route::get('/image/{id}', 'ImageController@showImage');
```

My store function in the ImageController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $image = new Image;
    $file = $request['image'];
    $img = base64_encode($file);
    $image->image = $img;
    Auth::user()->images()->save($image);


    return Redirect('/image');
}
```

My blade where I upload and post the image:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    <form id="image" type="POST" name="image" action="/imagepost">
        @csrf
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
@else
```

If you need more details, please ask!

I expect the image to be in the database but it actually shows the error message "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your form tag. To set the method, you should use the `method` attribute, not `type`:

```
<form id="image" method="POST" name="image" action="/imagepost">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your form tag. To set the method, you should use the method attribute, not type and use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for file upload:

```
<form id="image" method="POST" action="/imagepost" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
```